# xquery difference between "" and ()

Tags: xquery

What is the difference in evaluations of `$x` between the following assignments in Xquery:

`$x := ""`

versus

`$x := ()`

I am trying to determine the best method for evaluating `$x` in the case where one is evaluating whether there is a sequence.

For example how does `()` affect the evaluation of `$x` in the following, versus using `""`, where I'm testing the existence of HTTP request parameter(s) and putting them into a sequence. Does `()` still create a position in a sequence?:

```
let $x := if (request:get-parameter("keyword",()) != "")
            then
                for $kw in request:get-parameter("keyword",())
                return
                    if ($kw != "") 
                        then $kw
                    else ()
          else ()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: No, `()` does not create a position in the sequence; it's an empty sequence, where as an empty string is something that actually exists, can be iterated over, etc.